# Why does my Firebase DB being at max capacity freeze the UI of my application?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, websocket

I have a React application that is listening to Firebase events. It is not writing anything to the database, it is just updating state with an `.on('value', ...)` websocket listener.

This morning, my free "Spark" plan was at capacity for the number of connections. My test users all noticed that the UI had frozen. This has happened numerous other times when there is lots of DB activity. The freezes happen after the apps have already made the first connection—the UI slows down and freezes as the rate of activity increases.

I understand why I wouldn't get any new data if I were at max connections, but I **don't** understand why the UI is freezing. Shouldn't the `on` listener just not be being called?

Understanding this would probably also solve other issues I have (e.g. UI not updating until all `refs` have returned data, even though some come back earlier and should update the app sooner).

Here's my basic app structure:

```js
export default class App extends Component {

  [...]

  componentWillMount() {
    // I have an array of around 30 refs to listen to
    myFirebaseReferences.each(refId, => {
      firebase.database().ref(refId)
          .orderByKey()
          .on('value', (snapshot) => {
            const fbState = snapshot.val() || {};
            this.setState({[refId]: fbState});
          });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried taking out the `.orderByKey()`?

Comment: That was actually added to try and speed things up. The UI freezing was already happening without it. Also, AFAIK, it shouldn't affect things. It's entirely on the DB end. It's not like the JS app is downloading all the data and then ordering by key.

Comment: Have you fixed this problem, if so, what was your approach?